# Forcing use of catkin in jenkins builds

Tags: catkin, jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a package in which the CMakeLists.txt has to work without catkin as well (to build with cmake only). My current solution is to disable all catkin-specific commands (eg. catkin_package()) by taking them out with if statements, eg. `if(COMPILE_WITH_CATKIN) ..<catkin commands> ...`.  To set COMPILE_WITH_CATKIN I use the fact that CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX is defined only when building from within a catkin workspace:

`set (COMPILE_WITH_CATKIN NOT CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX)`

This works fine in a catkin workspace and with cmake only, but there are problems when building on Jenkins, when the CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX is not defined, but catkin still needs to be used (especially catkin_package()). So for building on jenkins, building with catkin has to be enforced. I currently have this work-around:

`set (ENFORCE_CATKIN false)  # set this to true for jenkins builds ONLY`
`set (COMPILE_WITH_CATKIN ENFORCE_CATKIN OR CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX)`

Before releasing the package with bloom, I manually set ENFORCE_CATKIN to true. Afterwards, for my source repository, I re-set it to false.

This is certainly not the prettiest solution. Is there a better way to detect when catkin commands would lead to errors (eg. catkin_package() command not found)?

Thanks for your help,
Jenny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235807/forcing-use-of-catkin-in-jenkins-builds/) by [JenniferBuehler](https://answers.ros.org/users/27040/jenniferbuehler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure about your use case but in CMake you can try to find `catkin` and then continue based on if it was found or not. Like this:

```
find_package(catkin)  # not passing REQUIRED
if(catkin_FOUND)
  # maybe call find_package again with COMPONENTS
  ..
else()
  ..
endif()
```

You can also mix this with a custom option like `COMPILE_WITH_CATKIN`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JenniferBuehler](https://answers.ros.org/users/27040/jenniferbuehler/) on 2016-06-01**:
Hi Dirk,

thanks for your quick reply.
I have tried this approach, however when compiling with cmake only, catkin is still found if it's installed...
I'm basically looking for a way to detect when compilation is happening from within a catkin workspace/jenkins.

**Comment by [JenniferBuehler](https://answers.ros.org/users/27040/jenniferbuehler/) on 2016-06-01**:
The use case is a couple of packages which should compile without catkin as well. They are general packages which are also used in projects outside ROS. I'd like to be able to put the package in a catkin workspace to compile as normal, and also be able to build with cmake separately.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-06-01**:
There is no distinguishing variable or anything else which lets you decide how CMake was being invoked. You could invert the logic and pass `COMPILE_WITHOUT_CATKIN` if `catkin` is on your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` but you don't want to use it.

**Comment by [JenniferBuehler](https://answers.ros.org/users/27040/jenniferbuehler/) on 2016-06-01**:
That is also a good idea, thanks! Will try this next time. For now, my approach works, I just wanted to know if there's a nicer way to achieve it. Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2016-06-01**:
We can't provide a public way (without authentication and authorization) to trigger builds on the farm. That would very likely result in abuse.